# angular service and http request

Tags: http, angularjs, angularjs-service

creating service

```
myApp.factory('serviceHttp', ['$http', function(http) {
  http.get($scope.url).then(function(result){
    serviceVariable = result;
  }
  return serviceVariable;
}
```

Controller

```
function appController($scope, serviceHttp){
  $scope.varX = serviceHttp;
  if(serviceHttp){
    // decision X;
  } else {
    // decision Y;
  }
}
```

view:

```
input(ng-if='varX') serviceHttp Exist
input(ng-if='!varX') serviceHttp noExist
```

The above code always shows `varX` not exist because app installs during `http` call of service. I want to use angular `service` to inject variables from server to make decision at time of booting the application.

Comment: `var` is an invalid variable name in javascript.

Comment: thats not the issue. edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rewrite factory by this way that returns promise:

```
myApp.factory('serviceHttp', ['$http', function(http) {

   var factory = {
       query: function () {
          var data = http.get($scope.url).then(function(result){
              return result;
           },
          function (result) {
            alert("Error: No data returned");
         });
           return data;
       } 
   }
   return factory;  
}]);
```

From controller:

```
serviceHttp.query().then(function (result) {
    $scope.varX =  = result;                            
}
```

Here is Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/793/)**</kbd>

*in demo we used other URL source*

Answer (score 2):

If i correct understand you, you should doing it like this:

```
 var app = angular.module('YourModule', []);
    app.factory("serviceHttp", function($http) {
        var serviceHttp={};

        serviceHttp.yourGetRequest = function(yourUrl) {

           return $http.get(yourUrl);
       };

        return serviceHttp;
    });
```

And for example, controller:

```
        var Controller = function($scope,serviceHttp) {
        $scope.varX='';
        $scope.loading = true;
      var returnArr = serviceHttp.yourGetRequest($scope.url).success(function(dataFromServer) {
$scope.loading = false;
$scope.varX = dataFromServer;
})

};
```

in view you can use ng-show, like this:

```
<div ng-show="loading" class="loading"><img src="../styles/ajax-loader-large.gif"></div>
```

When your application start loading, $scope.loading = true and this div shown, and when you get response from server $scope.loading became false and div doesn't show.